# Error while running php code

Tags: php, web-services, fatal-error

i'm making a small PHP application that uses some data to check whether it matches the records of the database or not(a prototype of a login process), but it gives me a (extra junk data error) and when commenting the header line to check the error it gives me that fatal error:

**Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\www\hh\login.php on line 22**

**The Code:**

```
<?php

header("Content-type: text/xml");

$host = "localhost";
$user = "muhammed";
$pass = "";
$database = "test";

$linkID = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die("Could not connect to host.");
mysql_select_db($database, $linkID) or die("Could not find database.");

$query = "SELECT * FROM info";
$resultID = mysql_query($query, $linkID) or die("Data not found.");

$name = "tahany";
$age  = 90;

while(true){
for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID);
    if ($row['Name'] == $name && $row['age'] == $age){
        $res = "login success";
        break;
    }else{
        $res = "failed to login";
    }
}
}

echo $res;

?>
```

Comment: Well, you have an infinite loop in "failed to login". While(true) was the clue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to increase the time out of PHP Script. Do this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
```

### Actual problem lies here in your while loop.

Your `while` loop is running in a infinite condition. Try changing it like . Always remember `while(true)` runs infinitely.

```
$i=0;
while($i==0){
for($x = 0 ; $x < mysql_num_rows($resultID) ; $x++){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID);
    if ($row['Name'] == $name && $row['age'] == $age){
        $res = "login success";
        break;
    }else{
        $res = "failed to login";
    }
}
$i=1; // Changing the flag to 1 , so while condition fails
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to optimize your code, There is no need of extra `for loop`.

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($resultID)){
    if ($row['Name'] == $name && $row['age'] == $age){
        $res = "login success";
    }else{
        $res = "failed to login";
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated move on `mysqli_*` functions asap.

Answer (score 1):

```
You getting fatal error because of infinite loop you are putting break in inner loop but outer loop is infinite.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can (and should) remove the `while (true)` statement from the code. It is not needed. This is what's causing your timeout. The `break` statement only breaks the inner `for`-loop and not the outer `while` loop.

Now, a fix for the while loop could be something like this:

```
$break_loop = false;
while (!$break_loop ) {
    // Keep your existing code as-is.
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            ...
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    // Always break the loop, whether or not the log-in was successful. 
    // We need to stop the while-loop anyhow.
    //
    // When the log-in was successful, we jumped out of the for-loop much
    // sooner.
    $break_loop = true;
}
```

So we use a temporary variable to keep the loop running until the variable is set to `true`. This happens when we jump out of the `for`-loop when the log-in is successful, or when all attempts failed.

But again, the `while`-loop is not needed because your `for`-loop handles it already.

Answer (score 1):

it is not good to use this code but it is useful
break 2;

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php